# jQuery functionality in C#

Tags: jquery, linq, xpath, windows-phone-8

I need to find values in a morass of erratically structured HTML. jQuery would make short work of this, but this isn't in a browser and JavaScript is not an option.

I have a DOM, courtesy of HtmlAgilityPack. XPath would also make short work of the problem, but this code runs on Windows Phone 8 and there is no XPath support.

I do have LINQ, but I don't really see how to apply it to the problem; LINQ is great for shallow wide stuff but tiresome for tall narrow trees.

I have a sinking feeling I'll have to write my own treewalker method that applies a predicate to every node. This massively sucks gigantic rocks. Has anyone got a better idea?

Comment: Not sure why linq to xml would be cumbersome?

Comment: It's a tree of unpredictable depth. It may well be possible to write a LINQ statement to do recursive descent into a tree but I don't know how. Also it's not XML, it's HTML. I realise I did mention XPATH implying it was XML but HtmlAgilityPack provides XPATH on the DOM... except on WP8.

Comment: Having discovered the Descendants(string tag) method I now feel pretty silly: once you can conveniently flatten the tree LINQ comes into its own.

Comment: Yeah I was going to mention that, but wasn't sure if there was some nuance I was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at CsQuery:

https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery

It might just do what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks, Magnus. Even though I've untangled my immediate problem this still looks worthwhile.

Comment: That library looks *awesome*.